# Is it possible to run code in the smart contract whenever an NFT serves its URI?

Tags: nft, erc-721, chainlink

I'm building a dynamic NFT. I want the NFT I am creating to change depending on other NFTs not in my control in the user's possession.

When properties in NFT A (ay arbitrary NFT) change, say who owns it or its URI, NFT B (the one I'm building), needs to run some logic.

Alternatively, if there's a service that can connect two NFTs, perhaps like chainlink's hybrid contracts, that would work better.

Of course. I could build a service that manually watches the NFTs, but that's a lot more work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a Chainlink [Keeper Compatible contract](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/) that should monitor NFT A for changes (make sure to mark `checkUpkeep` function as `view`). And then in the `performUpkeep` you should call the NFT B contract and execute whatever functionality you are planning to implement.